# Array{Float64,2} problem when multiplying matrixes Julia

Tags: arrays, types, casting, julia

I was doing something fairly simple with matrixes:

```
for i in 1:N
  X=XT[1:2,i]
  A[i]=X'*Sig*X+b
end
```

Where XT is an Array of arrays (1×5 Array{Any,2}) that I imported from Matlab, and by doing so I get X of type Array{Float64,2}. And Sig is a 2x2 matrix, also Array{Float64,2}.

The problem is: the result from X'*Sig*X is of Array{Float64,2} type, although having just one element. And I can't sum it to b.

I Know I can put a dot and make the sum, but if I do that, I will still have this array type, and will be storing that on the other Array, which can be a big mess.

Any ideas to solve it keeping it simple?

Comment: What is the dimension of A? is it also Array{Float64,2}, and what is its size? Do you want the result of the sum to be an array stored in A or just a scalar stored in A[i]?

Comment: This is odd. `XT[1:2, i]` should be a vector, not a matrix. Very strange.

Comment: I want it to be stored as Float64. A should be also Array{Float64,2}.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to include initialization for the arrays A and XT?  It matters how that was done.

Comment: I've edited it. As it happens, my array XT was not a normal matrix. And there lies the problem. It seems I can do XT[i][:] and get the correct dimension, but I don't know why it does not happen the other way.

Comment: Can you show _exactly_ what `A` looks like? Even your last edit does not completely clarify. If `A` is `1×5 Array{Any,2}`, then `A[1:2, i]` should give an error. Without showing a complete, runnable example, helping becomes very hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julia explicitly distinguishes between elements and arrays of elements. Some other languages, less explicit about types (like R and Matlab), treat a single-element Matrix as a number, and users get used to doing that implicitly. In Julia, however, these two things are fundamentally different - one is a container of numbers, the other is a number.

So the answer is simply, do `(X'*Sig)[1]` or `first(X'*Sig)` to get out the element. On coming versions of Julia you should be able to do `only(X'*Sig)` explicitly for containers with only one element.

It is simple and clear, just different from Matlab or R. There's actually a fundamental philosophical difference of what "simple" means in the languages. In R or Matlab I'd say "simple" means "not too many operation/characters". In Julia "simple" means "clear, explicit, straightforward to reason about". It's just a different philosophy that will take some time adapting to.

Comment: That was my first approach for an answer but there is actually another mistake in OP's code: `X=XT[1:2,i]` gives the first two elements (the first two arrays) in  `XT` (a `1D` array of arrays) when  `i` is 1 otherwise an error. The first line does not index `XT` appropriately for the purpose. There is also `A[]` to access the only element.

Comment: `MAT.jl` reads row or column vectors of MATLAB as Julia's 2D matrices. The OP's `1x1` matrix problem would be avoided if `X` was made a `Vector` with, for example, `vec`. `v'*M*v` automatically uses `LinearAlgebra.dot` giving a scalar rather than an array and does so in a performant way avoiding a matrix multiplication. The credit goes to Andreas Peter who explained this solution on #helpdesk channel of Julia Slack  today.

Comment: Nice, great perspective.